# TortoiseSVN tree conflict on merge with no previews

Tags: tortoisesvn, svn-merge-reintegrate

I just installed VisualSVN 3.5.6, and I'm using Tortoise SVN 1.8.11.

I followed these steps:

1. Using the VisualSVN manager I created a new repository called "test"
2. Within this repository I created project_1/trunk and project_1/branches
3. I checked out project_1/trunk
4. I added a new file to trunk (foo.c), the first line simply reading "initial commit"
5. I SVN add/commit this file
6. Using TortoiseSVN I make a new branch from trunk and call it project_1/branches/001
7. In trunk I modify foo.c and alter the first line and svn commit to trunk
8. In the branch I also modify line 1 of foo.c, with a different value, and commit to the branch
9. I now try to Merge into trunk from the branch

As expected I get a tree conflict. I also see an error which says, "One or more conflicts were produced while merging r3:4 into 'D:\svn local tests\project_1 trunk' -- resolve all conflicts and rerun the merge to apply the remaining
unmerged revisions"

In my trunk working copy I have the .svn folder, and foo.c which is flagged as conflicted. There is no other file.

If I right click and SVN Edit Conflicts on foo.c I see this:

[image]

I guess I have to manually use Winmerge (or similar) to compare the file from branch and trunk, apply whatever changes I want to the trunk file, marked it as resolved, then Merge once again? I had expected the edit conflict window to show me a side-by-side diff so I could move the changes to a %resolved pane.

I also note the Source Left URL is:
https://foo.bar.com:444/svn/test/project_1/trunk/foo.c@3
This gives me a 404 error, but if I remove @3 the URL is fine (maybe VisualSVN doesn't support showing revisions I suppose?)

Comment: With the Trunk file I edited conflicts, and choose to keep my working copy (which matched what was in trunk). I then merged from the branch to trunk once again, again it told me there was a conflict, but this second time I could click an "Edit Conflict" button and it gave me a side by side diff to work with. Having to do two merges seems redundant. On the first Merge could it not just have allowed me to Edit Conflicts and see the side by side diff?

Comment: I further note that repeating identical steps except with TortoiseSVN 1.9.4 yields different results. Repeating the same steps *sometimes* during the merge it gives you the option to edit conflicts during the merge, and other times it gives the same dialog attached above. With each test I'm deleting my test repo and starting from scratch to ensure one test is not affecting another.